# Автоматическое создание таблицы SQL во время работы кода

Tags: java, mysql, веб-программирование, mvc, hibernate

Пишу форум, человек создает новый топик в котором множество людей может оставить свое сообщение.

Топики хранятся в таблице "topic", сообщения в "messages". Работает все через Hibernate.

Но получается, что все сообщения со всех топиков хранятся в одной таблице. Это же не хорошо.

Я хочу, что-бы новый топик создался, и создалась новая таблица с именем топика и в ней были сообщения только этого топика! Подскажите как это реализовать?

Comment: По моему лучше оставить как есть, т. к. создавать новые таблицы не есть хорошо.

Comment: А если у меня сайт крутой и миллионы сообщений получается? Это же великая нагрузка на обработку. т.е. нужно достать сообщение, проверить, соответствует ли оно теме, затем, соответствует ли топику. И если все хорошо, то вывести на экран.

Comment: Лучше тогда разделить топики на группы

Comment: "_Это же не хорошо_" ... НЕТ - это замечательно, именно так и только так должно быть. Таблицы _никогда_ не должны создаваться во время работы приложения. У топика должен быть ID. сам топик _должен_ быть в таблице топиков. В таблице сообщений у сообщения _должен_ стоять ID топика. И по этому полю _должен_ быть создан индекс, поиск по индексу на точное равентсво происходит практически мгновенно.

Comment: Значит я зря волнуюсь о производительности. Спасибо за ответы!